# How to fix bootstrap 4 carousel wordpress loop post?

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

How to have dynamic bootstrap 4 carousel in Wordpress custom post types ?

code :

```
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <?php
            $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'category_name'=> 'slider'
        );

        $posts = new WP_Query( $args );
        while( $posts->have_posts() ):
            $posts->the_post();
        ?>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('full')?>" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
        </div>
        <?php 
                endwhile;
                wp_reset_query();
            ?>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="fa fa-square fa-lg " aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

I want to make carousel dynamic using Wordpress custom post types

Comment: `how can fix that?` what is the error?

Comment: So if your above code is accurate, you're applying `.active` to every `.carousel-item` ... have you tried addressing that to see if it is your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Error is right here:

```
<img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('full')?>" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
```

change it to

```
<img src="<?= the_post_thumbnail_url('full') ?>" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
```

you need to echo the result of a function to output the data.

Comment: What is that image suppose to tell me? Swap the line in your code with my code exactly, if you noticed I don't use <?php I used <?=

Comment: I did what I was told and the picture was the result

Comment: So is that what you were looking for then?

Comment: No. I have all the pictures in one place!! https://www3.0zz0.com/2019/03/27/21/930436695.png

Comment: Try taking <div class="carousel-inner"> out of your while loop, you're making 3 carousel inners

Answer (score 0):

**Solution-1:**

Your above query should work add your while loop after carousel-inner div and  try to remove active class
instead active class add a counter

before your while loop add a variable $i=0; and in active class add belo code

```
<?php if($i==0) echo 'active'; ?>
```

and inside loop add $i++;

thats it.

**Solution-2:**

if you are not able to get result from your above query try this one

```
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <?php $slider = get_posts(array('post_type' => 'carouselposttype', 'posts_per_page' => 3)); ?>
                <?php $count = 0; ?>
                <?php foreach ($slider as $slide) : ?>
                    <div class="carousel-item single-slider <?php echo ($count == 0) ? 'active' : ''; ?>">
                        <img class="bannerimg" src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($slide->ID)) ?>" alt="First slide">
                        <div class="carousel-caption  d-m">
                            <?php echo $slide->post_content ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php $count++; ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </div>
```

Hope this will help someone.
Thanks